# How to load Dynamically loaded elements in webpage using Selenium when browser is minimized?

Tags: javascript, selenium

I have to use selenium to load all the elements i.e. "li" of a very long list which shows only about 15 elements at a time and is dynamically loaded as we scroll down. For loading all list items, I have to use
`(JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,window.innerHeight)"`

This works fine when browser is open but when i minimize the driver browser, it keeps on scrolling but **no new elements are generated** and hence i can't extract them. It works fine again when i maximize the driver. I have to make it work when minimized.

Comment: Why do you want to _minimize the driver browser_ ? Did you look at _Headless WebDrivers_ ?

Comment: Because people have to do other tasks while selenium is doing it's task and it is annoying for them to keep it maximized. I wish to do it without headless if possible.

Comment: Of-coarse people have to do their tasks while _Selenium_ is doing it's task in a isolated _Test Lab_ free from _Manual Intervention_.